# The greatest eigenvalue

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am searching for any estimates of the greatest eigenvalue for non-symmetric 3(5)-diagonal matrix $A$, i.e. any information about estimates like

$$|\lambda_n|<F(a_{ij}), $$
where $A=[a_{ij}];i,j=\overline{1,n},F$- any function. This estimate will be used in computations, so the better it is, the quicker the computation is. Could you advise any source? Any help will be sincerely appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "$3(5)$-diagonal"?

Comment: I mean tridiagonal matrix, something like
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {a_{11}} & a_{12} &{0} & {0}& {..} &{..} \\
   {a_{21}} & {a_{22}} & {a_{23}}& {0} &{..}  \\
    {0}&{a_{32}}&{a_{33}}&{a_{34}}&{0} &{0} &{..}\\
    {..}
\end{matrix} \right]$$
5-diagonal means almost the same, but there are 5 elements in each line (except some at the beginning and the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ can be bounded from above by any matrix norm consistent with a certain vector norm (e.g., a matrix operator norm), we have
$$
\rho(A)\leq\min\{\|A\|_1,\|A\|_{\infty}\}.
$$
This bound can be also obtained by using the [Geršgorin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) on $A$ and $A^T$. Since the $1$-norm and the $\infty$-norm involve maxima of absolute column/row sums (and, in addition, they are easy to compute), they are likely to provide a reasonably accurate estimate for sparse/banded matrices.

In addition, as far as I know, the bound is asymptotically exact for symmetric 3-diagonal Toeplitz matrices (with $n\rightarrow\infty$).

Comment: Indeed, this estimate is better, than with Frobenius norm (I checked this :) ) Thanks, you greatly helped!

Answer (score 1):

$|\lambda_n| \le \|A\|$ for any induced matrix norm.  There are many estimates of these, e.g. you could bound it by the Frobenius norm which is 
$\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2}$.

Comment: Thank you,@Robert Israel. It's useful, but this estimate is a bit coarse for computations

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about the type of estimate you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate question, i have edited the text